how to know how much implementation detail to include?
In my software patent application, I've described the main features in detail.
There are many optional features. I am not sure how much implementation details are needed for these optional features.
For example, one of the optional features is that the user can toggle X off/on, the user can reveal or keep private XYZ, etc.
For these examples, do I need to include details of how the users toggle X off/on, etc?
These features are not new to software development or web development. So would it be obvious to implement with the current details as is?

Are these aspects likely to be limitations in claims and do they have significant user appreciated value?

By "limitations in claims", do you mean will the optional features contribute to dependent claims? I think they will.

Firstly, if it's not something you're claiming, then presumably the only reason to include it is to prevent others from claiming it. In this case, it is sufficient if the description renders it obvious, and any more is wasted effort.
However, if it is something you're claiming, then you need to do more than render it obvious. For example, you also need to make sure the claim has sufficiently definite scope. As a sub-example, if you use means-plus-function language in the claim, you must have actual step-wise breakdown for that function that limits the claim to a particular implementation that is more narrow than the bare function itself, even if that implementation would be obvious to a person of ordinary skill.
Unfortunately, there are too many more rules to list them all. I am not aware of a simple "rule of thumb" for the appropriate level of detail in a patent specification, and it depends very much on how the claims are worded.

How common is to disclose additional, optional features, just so that other people cannot patent it? That was my first intent. I don't need to claim these, as they fall under the independent claim. But certainly, it would be important to prevent someone else from claiming it.

@BearBileFarmingisTorture In my experience fairly common.
